# How would Hermann Weyl's development of the time "continuum" be handled in contemporary mathematical language?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, parametrization

The source of the quoted material is [Space-Time-Matter by Hermann Weyl](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006)

I started trying to summarized the following development of the mathematical treatment of parameterized time.  Then I realized there are many subtleties involved, and much of the discussion can probably be handled better using more modern terminology.

I would call his mathematical model of time a one-dimensional manifold formed of a strictly ordered infinite, unbounded set.  It evidently has some topological structure.  I'm not sure where the notions of homogeneity and congruence (ability to compare different lengths of time) fall into the taxonomy of mathematical concepts.  I'm also not sure Weyl gives enough structure to call his manifold a continuum in the sense of Cantor. (A concept he took issue with.)

I have to qualify my characterization of his model as a set.  What he develops is (apparently) a point set.  But that is **merely a model** of continuum *a priori*.

Finally, I believe the group structure described at the end is that of a Lie Group.

So I ask: **how might the structure described by Weyl be expressed in current mathematical language?**

> To be able to apply mathematical conceptions to questions of
> Time we must postulate that it is theoretically possible to fix
> in Time, to any order of accuracy, an absolutely rigorous **now**
> (present) as a **point of Time**---i.e., to be able to indicate points of
> time, one of which will always be the earlier and the other the
> later. The following principle will hold for this "order-relation".
> If $A$ is earlier than $B$ and $B$ is earlier than $C$, then $A$ is earlier
> than $C$. Each two points of Time, $A$ and $B$, of which $A$ is the
> earlier, mark off a **length of time**; this includes every point
> which is later than $A$ and earlier than $B$. The fact that Time is
> a form of our stream of experience is expressed in the idea of
> **equality**: the empirical content which fills the length of Time $AB$
> can in itself be put into any other time without being in any
> way different from what it is. The length of time which it would
> then occupy is equal to the distance $AB$. This, with the help of
> the principle of causality, gives us the following objective criterion
> in physics for equal lengths of time. If an absolutely isolated
> physical system (i.e., one not subject to external influences) reverts
> once again to exactly the same state as that in which it was at
> some earlier instant, then the same succession of states will be
> repeated in time and the whole series of events will constitute a
> cycle. In general such a system is called a **clock**. Each period
> of the cycle lasts **equally** long.

> The mathematical fixing of time by **measuring** it is based upon
> these two relations, "earlier (or later) times" and "equal times".
> The nature of measurement may be indicated briefly as follows:

---

In the following paragraph the sentence translated as "A difference arises, however, in the case of three point-pairs." Is originally:

"Anders wird die Sache aber, wenn wir zu drei Zeitpunkten übergehen."

"However things are different when we go to three time-points."

Unfortunately there are a large number of such errors in the translation.

---

> Time is homogeneous, i.e., a single point of time can only be given
> by being specified individually. There is no inherent property
> arising from the general nature of time which may be ascribed to
> any one point but not to any other; or, every property logically
> derivable from these two fundamental relations belongs either to
> all points or to none. The same holds for time-lengths and
> point-pairs. A property which is based on these two relations and
> which holds for **one** point-pair must hold for every point-pair $AB$
> (in which $A$ is earlier than $B$). A difference arises, however, in the
> case of three point-pairs. If any two time-points $O$ and $E$ are
> given such that $O$ is earlier than $E$, it is possible to fix conceptually
> further time-points $P$ by referring them to the unit-distance $OE$.
> This is done by constructing logically a relation $t$ between three
> points such that for every two points $O$ and $E$, of which $O$ is the
> earlier, there is one and only one point $P$ which satisfies the
> relation $t$ between $O$, $E$ and $P$, i.e., symbolically,
> $$
> OP = t \cdot OE
> $$
> (e.g., $OP = 2 \cdot OE$ denotes the relation $OE = EP$). **Numbers** are
> merely concise symbols for such relations as $t$, defined logically
> from the primary relations. $P$ is the "time-point with the
> **abscissa $t$ in the co-ordinate system** (taking $OE$ as unit length)".
> Two different numbers $t$ and $t^{*}$ in the same co-ordinate system
> necessarily lead to two different points; for, otherwise, in consequence
> of the homogeneity of the continuum of time-lengths,
> the property expressed by
> $$
> t \cdot AB = t^{*} \cdot AB,
> $$
> since it belongs to the time-length $AB = OE$, must belong to **every**
> time-length, and hence the equations $AC = t \cdot AB$, $AC = t^{*} \cdot AB$
> would both express the same relation, i.e., $t$ would be equal to $t^{*}$.
> Numbers enable us to single out separate time-points relatively to
> a unit-distance $OE$ out of the time-continuum by a conceptual,
> and hence objective and precise, process. But the objectivity of
> things conferred by the exclusion of the ego and its data derived
> directly from intuition, is not entirely satisfactory; the co-ordinate
> system which can only be specified by an individual act (and then
> only approximately) remains as an inevitable residuum of this
> elimination of the percipient.

> It seems to me that by formulating the principle of measurement
> in the above terms we see clearly how mathematics has come to
> play its rôle in exact natural science. *An essential feature of
> measurement is the difference between the "determination" of an
> object by individual specification and the determination of the same
> object by some conceptual means.* The latter is only possible
> relatively to objects which must be defined directly. That is why
> a **theory of relativity** is perforce always involved in measurement.
> The general problem which it proposes for an arbitrary
> domain of objects takes the form: (1) What must be given such that
> relatively to it (and to any desired order of precision) one can single
> out conceptually a single arbitrary object $P$ from the continuously
> extended domain of objects under consideration? That which has
> to be given is called the **co-ordinate system**, the conceptual
> definition is called the **co-ordinate** (or abscissa) of $P$ in the co-ordinate
> system. Two different co-ordinate systems are completely
> equivalent for an objective standpoint. There is no property, that
> can be fixed conceptually, which applies to one co-ordinate system
> but not to the other; for in that case too much would have been given
> directly. (2) What relationship exists between the co-ordinates
> of one and the same arbitrary object $P$ in two different co-ordinate
> systems?

> In the realm of time-points, with which we are at present concerned,
> the answer to the first question is that the co-ordinate
> system consists of a time-length $OE$ (giving the origin and the
> unit of measure). The answer to the second question is that the
> required relationship is expressed by the formula of transformation
> $$
> t = at' + b \text{; } (a > 0)
> $$
> in which $a$ and $b$ are constants, whilst $t$ and $t'$ are the co-ordinates
> of the same arbitrary point $P$ in an "unaccented" and "accented"
> system respectively. For all possible pairs of co-ordinate systems
> the characteristic numbers, $a$ and $b$, of the transformation may be
> any real numbers with the limitation that $a$ must always be positive.
> The aggregate of transformations constitutes a **group**, as
> their nature would imply, i.e.,

> 1. "identity" $t = t'$ is contained in it.

> 2. Every transformation is accompanied by its reciprocal in
>    the group, i.e., by the transformation which exactly cancels its
>    effect. Thus, the inverse of the transformation $(a, b)$, viz., $t = at' + b$,
>    is $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}, -\dfrac{b}{a}\right)$, viz., $t' = \dfrac{1}{a}t - \dfrac{b}{a}$.

> 3. If two transformations of a group are given, then the one
>    which is produced by applying these two successively also belongs to
>    the group. It is at once evident that, by applying the two transformations
>    $$
>    t = at' + b
>    t' = a't" + b'
>    $$
>    in succession, we get
>    $$
>    t = a_{1} t" + b_{1}
>    $$
>    where $a_{1} = a \cdot a'$ and $b_{1} = (ab') + b$; and if $a$ and $a'$ are positive,
>    so is their product.

#### Sketch of beginnings of a rough draft

The following is my scribbling about the topic.  I am not pretending that the use of mathematical terms is proper.  It's not even close to a comprehensive answer.  The main reason I'm including it here is to motivate a possible approach to the topic.  In particular note that my "clock" is far more abstract than Weyl's.  I make no appeal to physical reasoning.  In fact my clock could be thought of as noting more than a selection of elements satisfying certain criteria.

### The Temporal Continuum

The **temporal continuum** is an ideal form conceived as an infinite indivisible transcendental existence.  Hopefully I will find time to unpack that metaphysical gibberish. For present purposes, take that to mean that we can think of time as isomorphic to the ideal Euclidean line.  The line itself is indivisible.  That is, no part can be separated from its adjacent parts.  The line can be "marked" with infinite precision using dimensionless points.  Whether those points of location are constituents of the line is not addressed.

Between any two distinct points on the line lies a segment of the line, which can be marked by a point distinct from the delimiting points, succeeding the first delimiter and preceeding the second delimiter. A representation  of the segment can be rigidly transported along the line as a standard of comparison.

[Unfinished due to technological  problems]

The **temporal continuum model** $\mathbb{X}$ is an unbounded, infinite,
homogeneous, strictly ordered set of **instants**. The ordering
is denoted $t_{1}<t_{2}$ and stated: instant $t_{1}$ is earlier
than instant $t_{2}$. For any bounded set of instants, there is an
earliest (also called the first, beginning, initial, etc.,) instant;
and a latest (also called the last, final, ending, etc.,) instant.
We shall call this ordering **chronological**.

In this context *homogeneous* means that instants have no intrinsic
distinguishing attributes, and are only distinguished by their relative
place in the continuum.

Between any two instants there is at least one additional instant
which is later than the the first and earlier than the last.

Every pair of instants delimits a **period**. A **clock** is a device that
enumerates instants in increasing chronological order. Each enumeration
is called a **tick** of the clock.  All periods delimited by a sequential
pair of enumerations from the same clock are said to be equal in **duration**.
Such a period is called a clock period of **unit duration**. This duration
is also called a **unit of time**. The period formed by a sequence of
$n$ adjacent clock periods is said to have a duration of $n$ units
of time. Two periods formed of the same number of adjacent clock periods
are said to be of equal duration. Indicating the enumeration of clock
ticks using integer subscripts we say the period $P_{1}=\left[t_{0},t_{n}\right]$
has a duration of $n=n-0$ units, and for $0\le m\le n$ the period
$P_{2}=\left[t_{m},t_{n}\right]$ has duration $p=n-m.$ If either
of the inequalities hold, then $p<n$ and we say the duration of $P_{1}$
is greater than, or longer than that of $P_{2}$.

We now introduce the requirement that a clock shall have the ability
to fractionally enumerate unit clock periods such that each unit period
has the same number of fractional periods. Each fractional period
delimited by a sequential pair of fractional enumerations is said
to be of equal duration to that of any other such fractional period
determined by the same clock. This method of uniform subdivision is
assumed to be recursively applicable to an arbitrary number of levels.

Two clock which enumerate the same instants (possibly with offset enumeration) are said to be **coinciding**. Two coinciding clocks with identical enumeration are said to be **synchronized**. Coinciding clocks are said to be **identical clocks**. But it is possible to have identical clocks which do not coincide. Two clocks are identical if all unit periods have the same pattern of interleaving instants. That is, for example each unit tick of the first clock falls in the $n^{th}$ fractional period of each unit period of the second clock.

Comment: Without reading everything: What fits at the start is that the space of "times" is 1) a set, b) has a transitive relation on it ($≤$), c) has the structure of an affine vectorspace over $\Bbb R$ that is compatible with the ordering (ie if $a,b\in T$, $a≤b$, $v\in V$ then $a+v≤b+v$). common sense indicates that the ordering $≤$ shoud at least be a partial ordering. At some point he makes some remarks that suggest the ordering in b) should also be total.

Comment: Removing the "continuum theory" tag from this question was inane.   This topic is the fundamental reason continuum theory has relevance to mathematical physics.

Comment: I added some of my own musings (including my own terminology) to the question.  What you are calling "times", I have come to call "instants".  Dividing time into different times delimited by specific times can be tricky.  Although I have done the same as you in promulgating a set of instants as the definition of the temporal continuum, this has the same deficiency as "point" in Euclidean geometry.  As "point" only has meaning in the context of "space".  And I won't even mention Heisenberg.