# What is meant by Hermann Weyl's proof by homogeneity of the bijective property of the affine parameterization of the time continuum?

Tags: proof-explanation, parametrization

This is a specific question I have regarding my broader question: [How would Hermann Weyl's development of the time "continuum" be handled in contemporary mathematical language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4503357/342834)

I've corrected an obvious error in the translation.  See the link for the original translation.  There may still be a problem with the wording, since it seems to be introducing a proof by contradiction, but then fails to show a contradiction.  At the end of this post is a copy of what I believe to be the text that was translated.  There is another edition with different wording and ordering.

> Time is homogeneous, i.e., a single point of time can only be given
> by being specified individually. There is no inherent property
> arising from the general nature of time which may be ascribed to
> any one point but not to any other; or, every property logically
> derivable from these two fundamental relations belongs either to
> all points or to none. The same holds for time-lengths and
> point-pairs. A property which is based on these two relations and
> which holds for **one** point-pair must hold for every point-pair $AB$
> (in which $A$ is earlier than $B$). A difference arises, however, in the
> case of three time-points. If any two time-points $O$ and $E$ are
> given such that $O$ is earlier than $E$, it is possible to fix conceptually
> further time-points $P$ by referring them to the unit-distance $OE$.
> This is done by constructing logically a relation $t$ between three
> points such that for every two points $O$ and $E$, of which $O$ is the
> earlier, there is one and only one point $P$ which satisfies the
> relation $t$ between $O$, $E$ and $P$, i.e., symbolically,
> $$
> OP = t \cdot OE
> $$
> (e.g., $OP = 2 \cdot OE$ denotes the relation $OE = EP$). **Numbers** are
> merely concise symbols for such relations as $t$, defined logically
> from the primary relations. $P$ is the "time-point with the
> **abscissa $t$ in the co-ordinate system** (taking $OE$ as unit length)".
> Two different numbers $t$ and $t^{*}$ in the same co-ordinate system
> necessarily lead to two different points; for, otherwise, in consequence
> of the homogeneity of the continuum of time-lengths,
> the property expressed by
> $$
> t \cdot AB = t^{*} \cdot AB,
> $$
> since it belongs to the time-length $AB = OE$, must belong to **every**
> time-length, and hence the equations $AC = t \cdot AB$, $AC = t^{*} \cdot AB$
> would both express the same relation, i.e., $t$ would be equal to $t^{*}$.

As I understand this, the definition of
$$
OP = t \cdot OE
$$
means $t$ can be understood as an "index" to exactly one ordered pair $\left\{OP,OE\right\}.$  But this does not prove that $t$ is unique.

To prove the uniqueness of $t$ we argue as follows: if
$$t \cdot AB = t^{*} \cdot AB$$
holds for any time-length $AB,$ homogeneity requires the condition to hold for all time-lengths. It seems to me that this, in itself proves that $t=t^{*}$.  At least $t$ and $t^{*}$ are equivalent in the role of indicating a time-point.

If
$$P=P^{*}\text{, }t \cdot OE = OP \text{ and }t^{*} \cdot OE = OP^{*},$$
then
$$t \cdot OE = t^{*} \cdot OE.$$

This is just an instance of $t \cdot AB = t^{*} \cdot AB$.  So if my first conclusion is correct, then the assertion that $P=P^{*}\iff t=t^{*}$ follows.  But that doesn't appear to be what was intended.

So what does the proof really mean?

[image]